# Delegation Event Model pattern Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, delegation

When applying this pattern Delegation Event Model, is it correct to put ALL the code in the `fire...` methods and pass the parameters from the public method?

Like this

```
public void addBananas(Banana banana) {
    fireBananaAdded(banana);  
}

private void fireBananaAdded(Banana banana) {
    //Create event etc and add banana to list here
}
```

Or should I have the add to list part in this example in the `addBananas` method instead? Because if I do it this way I will not have the opportunity to "attach" the banana object to the event-object which will be passed to the listeners, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put as much logic in `addBanana()` that is related to actually adding the Banana as I can.

When I'm done with `addBanana()`, I would call `fireBananaAdded()` which would generate the appropriate `BananaAddedEvent` and send it to the `BananaAddedListeners` (or just `BananaListeners`, which ever you have.)

To put the ADD logic in the FIRE method is simply, well, BANANAS!

```
public void addBananas(Banana banana) {
    if(BananaHolder.hasRoom()) {
        BananaHolder.add(banana);
        fireBananaAdded(banana);  
    }
}

private void fireBananaAdded(Banana banana) {
    BananaAddedEvent event = new BananaAddedEvent(banana);
    for(BananaListener listener : listenersByType(Banana.class)) {
        listener.bananaAdded(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I took some liberties in the naming conventions, because it was aPEELing to do so. Okay I need to stop with the puns, or people will think I'm fruity. Gah! Stop that, glow!